# How can I constrain column widths without text clipping or wrapping?

Tags: html, css, html-table, clipping

I would like to constraint table columns width with no text clipping (no wrapping).

I came accross many many threads on Stackoverflow (sorry for duplicates), but none of them really gives straightforward solutions, even though I believe it is a rather simple issue...

First all of all, do I have to contrainst both header and content column width ?

I don't really want to insert `div` inside `th` / `td` (I haven't found straightforward solution anyway).

I believe that the `white-space: nowrap;` and `text-overflow: clip;` table styles width `<th style="width: 100px>...</th>` (idem `td`) would be enought, but it doesn't work). Does the CSS order of them matter?

I don't understand why something as simple as follows doesn't work..

```
<th style="width: 72px; text-overflow: clip; white-space: nowrap;">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz</th><!-- Of course, specified in CSS file -->
```

and would like to see something like:

```
----------------
   |ABCDEFG|
----------------
```

**UPDATE**

CSS styles

```
th {
    max-width: 72px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: clip;
    overflow: hidden;
}

td {
    max-width: 72px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: clip;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Razor page

```
<tH @Html.Raw(Helpers.HTMLTagAttribute(Enums.FieldType.Date))>
...
<td @Html.Raw(Helpers.HTMLTagAttribute(Enums.FieldType.Date))>
...
```

Where the helper method `HTMLBodyTagStyleAttributes(FieldType fieldType)` uses the `HTMLWidth(FieldType fieldType)` defined as follows with `FieldType` an enum relative to each column:

```
private static string HTMLWidth(FieldType fieldType)
{
    string width;

    switch (fieldType)
    {
        case FieldType.Date:
            width = "72px";
            break;
        // ...
        default:
            width = "86px";
            break;
    }

    return width != "" ? $"max-width: {width};" : "";
}
```

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding a `max-width` and `overflow: hidden`, e.g.:

```
th {
  max-width: 72px;
  text-overflow: clip; 
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: OK thanks. I've just update my question which I finally implemented. It seems that I need to constraint both column width in the body and the header. I use helper methods to override the default `max-width` in the CSS file. Seems to work :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Fix the header only. Not the cell.
2. Use CSS properties `word-wrap` and `word-break`

```css
    div {
      word-wrap: break-word;
      word-break: normal;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I doesn't really correspond to what I'm looking, because it still shows all text (in several lines..) Perhaps, it is still OK if I constraint the row heights ?? I'm trying to fiddle my attributes with `overflow: hidden;` that I missed, but still have to use `min-width` and `max-width`.

Comment: Use text-overflow:ellipsis